# Redux Not Updating in Component Synchonously

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was under the impression that redux was synchronous but it does not seem to be in this case. I have this:

```
loadData() {
  const filterData = {};

  Object.values(this.props.filters).map(f => {
     filterData[f.filter] = f.selectedValue || '';
   });

   this.props.fetchData({filters: filterData}); //redux call to load data
}

filterOnSubmit(filter, value, display) {
 const newFilter = { filter, selectedValue: value, display };
 this.props.updateFilter(newFilter);
 this.loadData();
}
```

But the value of f does not include the selected value that is set BUT when I look at my redux devtools it is there. If I delay the mapping (or delay the `loadData` via putting it in a setState callback) it is there also.

action and reducer for reference:

```
case UPDATE_FILTER: {
   const newFilter = { ...state[action.payload.filter], ...action.payload };
   return { ...state, [action.payload.filter]: newFilter };
}

export function updateFilter(newFilterData) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_FILTER,
    payload: newFilterData
  };
}
```

Comment: Redux is synchronous, but React will not receive the new props until the next render cycle. if you want to respond to changes in the props, you should use one of the applicable lifecycle methods.

Comment: @SArnab How would this work? I tried watching for componentDidUpdate and then in that case calling my redux fetch, but that updates the component also and so rerenders forever. What I want to do is change the redux props and then use them to make an ajax call that updates the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the redux store update is synchronous, the changes are not reflected in the same React cycle, the updates go though a re-render state, calling update lifecycle method.

After updating the store, you can call the actions that need to be called on store update in lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate (or componentWillReceiveProps which is now soon to be deprecated)` or otherwise pass the filters to the loadData function directly

```
loadData(filters) {
  const filterData = {};

  Object.values(filters).map(f => {
     filterData[f.filter] = f.selectedValue || '';
   });

   this.props.fetchData({filters: filterData}); //redux call to load data
}

filterOnSubmit(filter, value, display) {
 const newFilter = { filter, selectedValue: value, display };
 this.props.updateFilter(newFilter);
 this.loadData(newFilter);
}
```

Using componentDidUpdate, you would write it like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   // you have to perform an isEqual check since simply using '===' will not work for comparing arrays
   if(!_.isEqual(prevProps.filters, this.props.filters)) {
       this.loadData();
   }
}
loadData() {
  const filterData = {};

  Object.values(this.props.filters).map(f => {
     filterData[f.filter] = f.selectedValue || '';
   });

   this.props.fetchData({filters: filterData}); //redux call to load data
}

filterOnSubmit(filter, value, display) {
 const newFilter = { filter, selectedValue: value, display };
 this.props.updateFilter(newFilter);
}
```

Comment: @PixMach Glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right way, use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to start a new fetch request. A thing you're possibly missing is an if-condition for changes of filter prop.

Docs remind about this:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
>   that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or
>   you’ll cause an infinite loop.

And for your case it might be something like this, depending on the shape of filters:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.filter !== prevProps.filter)
    this.loadData();
}
```

Depending on code outside, you also might consider using a deep comparison inside `if`. But, of course, the best way would be to stay with `===` comparison and optimize `mapStateToProps` from outside (e.g. use meomization).

Answer (score 0):

Do as SAmab said or move this

```
Object.values(this.props.filters).map(f => {
      console.log(f);
      filterData[f.filter] = f.selectedValue || '';
    });
```

to your render function.

Comment: The problem with this is that I then use the filterData to do an ajax call. If I put the ajax call in my render function the page crashes.

Comment: make sure to put your ajax call on a separate function and call it only once. If you don't this will lead to an infinity loop.